# How to set a timeout in NanoHttpd Server

Tags: android, http, timeout, nanohttpd

In my app, I create a local NanoHttpd server giving it the path of video file to serve.
then, start another app to play from the stream.Now, since I don't want that server to run forever.

- Is there any way I can know that other app has stopped receiving data(or is closed) or,
- can I put any timeout in NanoHttpd so that it closes itself.

I am new to nanohttpd, http. Any suggestion that gain the final result is welcome.

Comment: Please show your serve().

Answer (score 4):

set the SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT in NanoHttpd for your own TimeOut.
By default it is 5000.

Comment: Will this actually stop the server after the set timeout? I have a server that has been running for 2 hours now(intentionally though) and I'm still able to make requests to it. I didn't pass any timeout. If the default is 5000, shouldn't the server have closed by now?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late, but you can also set SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT when starting your NanoHTTPD server:

```
NanoHTTPD server = new NanoHTTPD(yourPort);
server.start(readTimeout);
```